# How to handle multiples accesses to azure service bus

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

my application is using Azure Service Bus to store messages. I have an Azure function called `HttpTriggerEnqueue`which allow me to enqueue messages. The problem is that this function can be invoked hundreds times in a little interval of time. When I call the `HttpTriggerEnqueue` once, twice, 10 times, or 50 times everything works correctly. But when I call it 200, 300 times (which is my use case) I get an error and not all messages are enqueued. From the functions portal I get the following error.

```
threshold exceeded [connections]
```

I tried both the .NET sdk and the HTTP request. Here is my code

HTTP REQUEST:

```cs
try
{
    var ENQUEUE = "https://<MyNamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<MyEntityPath>/messages";
    var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip });
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ENQUEUE);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var sasToken = SASTokenGenerator.GetSASToken(
                    "https://<MyNamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<MyEntityPath>/",
                    "<MyKeyName>",
                    "<MyPrimaryKey>",
                    TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
                );


    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", sasToken);

    request.Content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
    request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));

    var res = await client.SendAsync(request);
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

And the code using the SDK:

```cs
var qClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(MyConnectionString, MyQueueName);
var bMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message);
qClient.Send(bMessage);
qClient.Close();
```

I have the standard tier pricing on Azure. 
If I call the function 300 (for example) times in a little interval of time I get the error. How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Service Bus output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) to send messages to Service Bus from Azure Function. It will handle connection management for you, so you shouldn't be getting such errors.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be perfect for me

Comment: @Mikhail While using the Service Bus binding will definitely clean up your code please see my answer as the root issue here is with HttpClient and not with Service Bus

Comment: @JesseCarter Yes, that's what I meant by "connection management", probably I should have elaborated on that further. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: sorry if I remove the accepted answer. Your advice is useful, but I just tried and it don't actually fix the problem. I think that the actual issue as @JesseCarter say is the exhaustation of the number of socket

Comment: Your solution actually works. It seemed not to work because I was trying the functions on local and each function used about 40000 ms to complete. But when I published the project to Azure the response time dropped to 40 ms

Answer (score 2):

The actual issue here isn't with the Service Bus binding (although you should follow the advice that @Mikhail gave for that), it's a well known issue with `HttpClient`. You shouldn't be re-creating the HttpClient on every function invocation. Store it in a static field so that it can be reused. [Read this blog post for a great breakdown on the actual issue](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). The main point being that unless you refactor this to use a single instance of HttpClient you're going to continue to run into port exhaustion.

From the [MSDN Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client):

`HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Especially in server applications, creating a new HttpClient instance for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors.`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However I would like to use the Service Bus output binding as @Mikhail suggests. Is there any way to use the output binding avoiding the socket exhaustation?